# Strange Math 2.4

Tags: mathematics

***So...***
My teacher found out that I was receiving online help with my math, and let's just say she isn't very happy about it. During today's class, we were learning about converting between different bases, but when I got my assignment, she wouldn't tell me which base to convert into. She said that I should know how to do it with my online help. Can you figure out what base I am converting to, and what the answer to the last question should be?

$9186_{10}=2300$
$741_{10}=200000$
$79075_{10}=134000$
$31200_{10}=79$
$7696_{10}= \ ?$

Hint:

> As a note, solving these problems is really a science.

Hint 2:

> This, as you probably know, is not true base conversion. However, Excel may sometimes make the mistake my teacher did.

Comment: To confirm, does $9186_{10} = 2300$ mean that the number $n$ represented as $9186$ in base $10$ is also represented as $2300$ in the unknown base $b$?

Comment: Correct. If it seems ambiguous, could you clarify how I should fix it? : )

Comment: I think it’s fine. :) But I’m definitely stumped!

Comment: I minorly updated the hint to try an be more helpful. Good Luck! : )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is

> $7696_{10} = 10000000000$

Reasoning

> First convert the numbers on the left from decimal to hexadecimal.
>  $9186 \rightarrow 23e2$
>  $741 \rightarrow 2e5$
>  $79075 \rightarrow 134e3$
>  $31200 \rightarrow 79e0$
>  Notice now how the numbers on the right could also be interpreted (for example, by Excel) as decimal numbers written in scientific notation, i.e,
>  $23e2 \rightarrow 23 \times 10^2 = 2300$
>  $2e5 \rightarrow 2 \times 10^5 = 200000$
>  $134e3 \rightarrow 134 \times 10^3 = 134000$
>  $79e0 \rightarrow 79 \times 10^0 = 79$
>  In particular,
>  $7696 \rightarrow 1e10 \rightarrow 1 \times 10^{10} = 10000000000$

Comment: Congratulations! Wonderfully explained and perfectly correct, as well. : )